# Show image from documents folder

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I retrieve an image I have saved at the documents directory like this:

```
//set background image
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myFolder/back.png"];
            backgroundImage.image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

But it is not shown :(

What am I doing wrong?

PD:Yes, it has been saved with the same path and filename (no upper/lower case differences) and yes, I tried opening the image at that path and it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's 'backgroundImage' in your code? How is it used?

Comment: IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImage;

Comment: I have a nib where a UIImageView is used as the background. It is linked to that IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was being done in the wrong place. I was doing it at init instead of viewDidLoad.